# Dygraphs zoom synchronization resets y zoom of other

Tags: synchronization, zooming, dygraphs

I'm currently trying to plot some environmental data i.e. Temperature, Humidity and Pressure.
I'm displaying 3 separate graphs and want their x-axis synchronized,but y-axis zooms synchronized (completely different ranges)

I have set the graph up and everything works almost as expected, but:
after zooming the y-axis of one graph, zooming any axis of another graph resets all graph y-ranges to the default/auto.

Is there a way around this and is it possibly a bug or a feature? It can be seen at http://dygraphs.com/tests/synchronize.html, unclick the Range, and try zooming the y-axes of different graphs.

The code:

```
var sync = Dygraph.synchronize(gs,{
    zoom: true,
    selection: true,
    range: false //disable y-axis sync
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svititom/e4da0L8o/1/

Thanks!

Comment: If I have understood correctly, what you want is not to reset the y-axes zoom of the other graphs when you zoom on one?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To extend it, to not affect the y-axes unless the user manually changes it (i.e. unzoom or zoom).
Currently both zooming, and panning resets the y-axis zoom.

Comment: The jsfiddle you have uploaded is not working correcty, and shows errors in the javascript console. Could you update it so we can help you?

Comment: Fixed.
(My bad, uploaded the one directly from their examples and presumed it would work)